# Are LASSO coefficients raw or standardized?

Tags: r, lasso, glmnet

I'm doing binary classification and ran LASSO to try and do feature selection to reduce the parameters in the model. I have the coefficients from `glmnet` at the minimum lambda but am unsure how to interpret them. Most of the inputs to the model are test statistics/measurements of a sample. Is further normalization across all predictors before-hand needed to be able to say the coefficients are standardized? I saw similar questions but never saw a clear answer to this particular question, sorry if considered duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the glmnet documentation for the function `glmnet`:

> `standardize`
>
> Logical flag for x variable standardization, prior to fitting the model sequence. The coefficients are always returned on the original scale. Default is standardize=TRUE. If variables are in the same units already, you might not wish to standardize. See details below for y standardization with family="gaussian".

Comment: No. The second sentence states "**The coefficients are always returned on the original scale.**"