# When Normalize is true are the coefficients arising from LASSO normalized or in the original state?

Tags: python, regression-coefficients, scikit-learn, lasso, normalization

From this question: [Are LASSO coefficients raw or standardized?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192995/are-lasso-coefficients-raw-or-standardized)

I understand that when standardizing the data, the coefficients are returned to the original scale. Is this correct? Can I just plug in the coefficients the raw data I have an get a prediction value? Finally, is this true when normalizing as well?

I am using this: model=LassoCV(cv=10,selection='random',normalize=True,max_iter=1000000).fit(X_train,y_train)

when I do this:
Coefficients.append(model.coef_) will my Coefficients list be in normalized values or original?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you tell us? Try scaling one of your X variables by a ridiculous amount. Like, do X_train[:,0] *= 1e12. Then, see if you get a different coefficient out of LassoCV or not.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the particular software that you are using. (Software-specific questions are off-topic on this site unless there is some associated statistical issue.)

Standardization puts predictors on relatively comparable footings before penalization. Thus the software default *can be* to standardize first, do the penalization, then return predictor coefficients to the original scales. But you can't necessarily count on that.

Read the manual for the particular software that you are using. Or try out the coefficients you get with your analysis and see if the results make sense in the original versus the standardized scales.

Comment: Or multiply all the `Y_train` data by $1000$ but leave the `X_train` data as is and see whether the coefficients and prediction values change

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I am using sklearn and I cannot find in the manual such clarification.

Comment: @Magda so see what makes sense, based on your data and model results.